# How to ask user to input number in class function?

Tags: c++

I written this code and now i want to take input from user for increment, like how much user want to increase the number. How can i do that?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myClass
{
     friend void increment(myClass *, int);
   private:
     int topSecret;
   public:
     void display() {
        cout << "\n The value of the topSecret is " 
             <<topSecret;
     } 
     myClass();
};

// constructor of the class
myClass::myClass()
{
  topSecret = 100;
}

// Friend function definition
void increment(myClass *a, int i) 
{
  a->topSecret += i; // Modify private data
}

// showing the use of the friend function
main()
{
  myClass x;
  x.display();
  increment(&x, 20);
  x.display();
}
```

Current result is:

```
The value of the topSecret is 100
The value of the topSecret is 120
```

Comment: `std::cin >> variable` is a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myClass
{

private:
    int topSecret;
public:
    void increment(int);
    void display() { cout << "The value of the topSecret is: " << topSecret << "\n"; }
    myClass();
};
// constructor of the class
myClass::myClass()
{
    topSecret = 100;
}
// Friend function definition
void myClass::increment(int i)
{
    topSecret += i; // Modify private data
}
// showing the use of the friend function
int main()
{
    myClass x;
    x.display();

    int number;
    std::cout << "input number: ";
    std::cin >> number;
    x.increment(number);

    x.display();
}
```

Comment: How about direct initialization of the member in the constructor and increment operators? +1 btw ...